# Change component state in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to do animated menu like on [this site](https://chustynka.pl/) (I'm thinking now about the images below the navbar that move by themselves):

I've got a component with 3 states and each state indicates which image with link should be displayed. I believe I should use `setTimeout` to change the state of the component. I tried to do this in `componentDidMount`/`componentWillMount` methods but I receive the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'why' of undefined

That indicates, as far as I understand, that the state is not set? What am I doing wrong?

```
export default class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      why: true,
      shop: false,
      workshop: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(function(){
      if (this.state.why) {
        this.setState({why: false, shop: true, workshop: false})
      }
      else if (this.state.shop) {
        this.setState({why: false, shop: false, workshop: true})
      }
      else if (this.state.workshop) {
        this.setState({why: true, shop: false, workshop: false})
      }
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.why && 
          <a href='/'>
            <Image src={horizontal1}
              className='pics'
            />
          </a>
        }
        { this.state.shop && 
          <a href='/'>
            <Image src={horizontal2}
              className='pics'
            />
          </a>
        }
        { this.state.workshops && 
          <a href='/'>
            <Image src={horizontal3}
              className='pics'
            />
          </a>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `setInterval(function(){` to `setInterval(() => {` and `this` will be what you expect.

Comment: @Tholle thank you! Now I see that. If you wish to add your comment as the answer I could accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Please use fat arrow function to access constructor inside the setInterval

```
setInterval(()=> {
  if (this.state.why) {
    this.setState({why: false, shop: true, workshop: false})
  }
  if (this.state.shop) {
    this.setState({why: false, shop: false, workshop: true})
  }
  if (this.state.workshop) {
    this.setState({why: true, shop: false, workshop: false})
  }
}, 3000);
```